# Grouping some table cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm stuck on a small problem. Say I have a list of devices, placed throughout different locations. I output all these devices in a table list. Some of these devices happen to have the same location. 
Is it possible to somehow group these table cells, by formatting a bold/double line around these cells?
I know of the possibility of the multiple custom cells, but I'm hoping someone has a easier way :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like below

[image]

add the following code to your plain tableview and return the sections as per your number of locations and rows as per your number of devices in each location

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 2)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question but you can customize any cell to look the way you want it to depending on some data.

Let's say you setup an array of your devices with a name and location like so:

```
    // keys in your device object
NSArray *aKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"location", nil];
// 1st device (in location 1)
NSDictionary *device1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Device 1", @"Location 1", nil] forKeys:aKeys];
// 2nd device (in location 2)
NSDictionary *device2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Device 2", @"Location 2", nil] forKeys:aKeys];
// 3rd device (in location 1 like device 1)
NSDictionary *device3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Device 3", @"Location 1", nil] forKeys:aKeys];
// array of devices
NSArray *aDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:device1, device2, device3, nil];
```

In your tableView:(UITableView *)tv
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method you could then check for and highlight each type location. In this case I'm simply going to add a colored strip to the edge of the cell where the color changes depending on the location like so:

```
    if([[aDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"location"] == @"Location 1"){
    // if location is Location 1 then we'll add an ORANGE colored strip to the left indicating location 1
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"location1Cell"];
    if( cell == nil ) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"location1Cell"] autorelease];
        // colored strip
        UIView *vwLoc =  [[[UIView alloc] 
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
        [vwLoc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:vwLoc];
    }
} else if([[aDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"location"] == @"Location 2"){
    // if location is Location 2 then we'll add an YELLOW colored strip to the left indicating location 2
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"location2Cell"];
    if( cell == nil ) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"location2Cell"] autorelease];
        // colored strip
        UIView *vwLoc =  [[[UIView alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
        [vwLoc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:vwLoc];
    }
}
// if location 3, location 4, etc. ...
```

Comment: yeah this was my first idea as well, although the suggestion posted by Iphone_bharat is exactly what I was looking for! :) Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

for making cells in group you can use group table.

Comment: I prefer not to use that table-mockup, since it splits the devices.. It's just for making clear they are together, not to split them alltogether.